# Controller Not Found on prestashop 1.6 Admin panel

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have the message "Controller Not Found" when i try to see an order on my Prestashop Back-office.

The strange thing is that i have this error only on one order, and the others work correctly.

Do you have any idea ?

I'm on Prestashop 1.6.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post the all the error message?

Comment: Does your Apache log give more details?

Comment: The error message is very simple... "Controller Not Found" on red background!

Comment: The Apache log give no more details. At a moment of the request, the AdminOrdersController as change to AdminNotFoundController...

Answer (score 1):

Please check that file AdminOrdersController.php is there at the following path of your PrestaShop directory:

```
/controllers/admin
```

If there is a file there then you can also check the permission for that file, it might be a permission issue.

Comment: It is the case!

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting any  closing php tags. That fixed my issue.

Thanks. I'm having the same issue.. I put that code in a controller file. I found out the issue in case. The issue was that I love code highlighting and often put <?PHP at the top of the blade views and the Controller (logic .php file).

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class JoeSearchController extends Controller
{
public function delete($id)
{
DB::table('user')->where('userID', '=', $id)->delete();
return redirect('history deleted');
}
}